# do (tap) vs subscribe

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

Edit: Prior to RxJs 6, `tap` was called as `do` . Updated title to reflect tap too.

I would like to understand what is the best practice of using `.subscribe` and `.do` methods of Observables.

For example if I need to do some job after initial data is loaded from server

```
const init$: Observable<MyData> = this._dataService.getData();

init$
  .do((initialData: MyData) => {
    this.data = initialData; // at this step I am initializing the view
  })
  .switchMap(() => loadExtraData)
  .subscribe((extraData) => {
     doSomething(extraData, this._data); // I need this._data here
  });
```

I can do the same with `.subscribe`

```
const init$: Observable<MyData> = this._dataService.getData()
  .shareReplay(1);

init$
  .subscribe((initialData: MyData) => {
    this.data = initialData; // at this step I am initializing the view
  })

init$
  .combineLatest(loadExtraData)
  .subscribe(([initialData, extraData]) => {
     doSomething(extraData, initialData); // I need this._data here
  });
```

Which one is better and why?

Answer (score 26):

Edit: For RxJS 6 or above, Read `do` as `tap`.

> `do` is used for side-effects. `subscribe` is used to invoke an observable. Replacing `do` with `subscribe` creates undesired results. Replacing `subscribe` with `do` will not even invoke the stream.

Consider these examples :

Using **subscribe** :

```
const testObservable = Rx.Observable.create(function(observer){
   console.log('some heavy task, may be network call ');
   observer.next('success');
});

testObservable.subscribe(function(res){
    console.log('action 1');
});

testObservable.subscribe(function(res){
   console.log('action 2');
});
```

The output of the above code is

```
"some heavy task, may be network call "
"action 1"
"some heavy task, may be network call "
"action 2"
```

You can see the `Rx.Observable.create` got executed twice. Our goal is do it only once but *along with action 2, do action 1* also.

Using **do**:

```
const testObservable = Rx.Observable.create(function(observer){
   console.log('some heavy task, may be network call ');
   observer.next('success');
});

testObservable
    .do(function(res){
        console.log('action 1');
    })  
    .subscribe(function(res){
        console.log('action 2');
    });
```

The output would be

```
"some heavy task, may be network call "
"action 1"
"action 2"
```

This is what we actually wanted. We need 'action 2' but before that do 'action 1' also.

**Why is it called side effect**:

Because it will not affect the flow of stream unlike other operators. It takes the response , does something and even if it modifies the response the stream is going to ignore it . For ex:

```
testObservable
    .do(function(res){
        console.log('action 1');
        return res+'some other text';
    })  
    .subscribe(function(res){
        console.log('action 1');
    });
```

The above code will still give the same output as before. So no matter what you execute in `do` the stream is going to ignore it and proceed with its execution.

> If we are doing pure 'functional reactive programming' we don't want any side effects in the stream. So, `do` is discouraged and mostly used only for debugging purposes .

Comment: I don't see how this answer makes any sense. In the `do`-example, just put `console.log('action 1');` inside the `subscribe` callback?
If you want to avoid heavy tasks associated with creating a subscription, multicast the stream with something like `share`.

Comment: @blid The ex is just to illustrate diff between `tap` and `subscribe` . We can achieve the same many ways. That is not the goal of the ex. `share` is totally different concept IMHO, it just mirrors an observable.

Answer (score 3):

The Observable chain is not going to do anything until you use `subscribe()` that makes connections between operators. So you always have to use the `subscribe()` method.

The `do()` operator is intended to only make side-effects.

In my experience it's often not possible to do everything in `subscribe()` and you sometimes need to use `do()` because your application logic needs to make actions in a specific order.

So in general I'd try to avoid using `do()` and put most of my logic into `subscribe()`. Only if I had to perform actions in a different order I'd use `do()`.

Comment: The Observable chain is not going to do anything until you use `subscribe()` it's not properly true: difference between hot and cold observables.

Comment: @Hitmands Even if you have a hot Observable it can emit whatever it wants but the connection between operators is not created until you specifically call `subscribe()`. So not even `do()` is going to receive anything until you subscribe. Also, obviously OP isn't using hot Observables to get data when there's no observer to receive them.

Answer (score 3):

I do everything in `tap` (`do`), because it allows to return observable, and later concat it with other additional pipes. For example, you can use `tap` in service, always returning observable as result. It gives you more flexibility to process it as you want, and if tomorrow you decide to add more there, you don't have refactor subscribe to tap. Finally, I put subscribe only at the final end (before rendering) with just `.subscribe()` (nothing in the parentheses).
Also, it makes the code consistent - so you know all your side-effects are always in `tap`, not "something in tap and something in subscribe".

P.S. If you use Angular, often you can use `| async` pipe in view, which subscribes automatically, so it's one more reason to use .tap instead of .subscribe for side-effects.

Answer (score 1):

Hardly in any case you need `subscribe` in a service. If your data flow is done in a really reactive way, you only subscribe in consumers (who are represented by components in Angular) to run the whole stream shebang. This allows stream composition which is a basis of the reactive approach. Avoid saving something from an observer into local scope, it's also against stream purity. You may rather compose a stream to pass all necessary data or combine streams.

Comment: @andré-staltz suggests to use `.do` operator only for debugging and perform all side effects in `.subscribe` to avoid having hidden side effects