# HttpClient Interceptor forces request duplicates

Tags: angular, angular6

I like to have a HttpInterceptor (Angular 6), which adds Authorization Headers but also handles 401 to redirect to login page.
This is my code:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpErrorResponse, HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class JwtInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {


    constructor(private router: Router) {
    }

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        // add authorization header with jwt token if available
        let currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
        if (currentUser && currentUser.token) {
            request = request.clone({
                setHeaders: {
                    Authorization: `Bearer ${currentUser.token}`,
                },
            });
        }

        const req = next.handle(request);

        // ---------------- VVV ---------------
        req.subscribe(() => {
        }, (error: any) => {
            if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse && (error as HttpErrorResponse).status === 401)
                this.router.navigate(['public/login']);
        });
        // ---------------- ^^^ ---------------

        return req;
    }
}
```

All works fine execpt that the code inside the vvv / ^^^ comment enforces that the request is sent twice. Why this? OK, I probably have to subscriptions on the request because this interceptor subscribes and probably my service using the HttpClient.
Is there a bether way to solve this?

**Edit: Here are the dependencies from package.json**:

```
...
"@angular/compiler": "6.0.3",
"@angular/core": "6.0.3",
"@angular/http": "6.0.3",
"@angular/router": "6.0.3",
"rxjs": "^6.2.0",
"rxjs-compat": "^6.2.0",
"rxjs-tslint": "^0.1.4",
"zone.js": "^0.8.26"
...
```

Comment: can you included your logs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `do()` instead of `subscribe()`

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> { 
   // add authorization header with jwt token if available
        let currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
        if (currentUser && currentUser.token) {
            request = request.clone({
                setHeaders: {
                    Authorization: `Bearer ${currentUser.token}`,
                },
            });
        }
  return next.handle(request).do((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
    if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
      // do stuff with response if you want
    }
  }, (err: any) => {
    if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse {
      if (err.status === 401) {
        this.router.navigate(['public/login']);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

[Difference between do() and subscribe()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45321516/do-or-subscribe)

**Edit**

import `do` operator `import { do } from 'rxjs/operators';`

**Why do/tap get ignored when used as subscribe?**

The point here is that `do()` will not affect the flow of the stream, unlike other operators. It takes the response, does something and even if it modifies the response the stream is going to ignore it. When you try to use it as `subscribe()` it simply get's ignored as you have already returned stream in below statement

Comment: Thanks! But I get this error: `core.js:1598 ERROR TypeError: next.handle(...).do is not a function` in the browser console. And if I change `do()` to `tap()`: same error. Note it is Angular 6 with RxJS 6 (but also rxjs-compat). I added the dependencies in my question.

Comment: In angular 6.x, use the latest version of rxjs. Syntax changes to import operator `do`  operator. Use `import { do } from 'rxjs/operators';` might be it's work.

Comment: OK, with `import 'rxjs/add/operator/do'; `it works, thanks! It is a real mess with all this compatiblity/version differences... it also works with `.pipe(tap(...` - Very important: If we do not directly `return next.handle(request).do...` (but assign `next.handle(request)` to a variable and returning this one as I made it), it will never enter `.do`/ `.tap` part (in opposite to the `.subscribe`). Could you point out why this difference in your answer?

Comment: Please see the answer updated answer. If it answers your question, accept it to close the question.

Answer (score 0):

Install **rxjs-compat** and Try this, it's work for me.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpInterceptor,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpRequest,
  HttpEvent,
  HttpResponse,
  HttpErrorResponse
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { do } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class InterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  intercept(
    req: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    if (
      localStorage.getItem('JWT-TOKE') !== '' && 
      localStorage.getItem('JWT-TOKE') !== null
    ) {
      const JWT = localStorage.getItem('JWT-TOKE');
      req = req.clone({
        setHeaders: {
          Authorization: 'Bearer ' + JWT
        }
      });
    }
    return next.handle(req).do(
      (event: HttpEvent<any>) => {},
      (err: any) => {
        if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
          if (err.status === 401) {
            localStorage.clear();
            this.router.navigate(['/login']);
          }
        }
      }
    );
  }
}
```

**Update**

If You not using **rxjs-compat** then use tap instead of do, because of **do** is reserved keyword in javascript.

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import {
    HttpInterceptor,
    HttpHandler,
    HttpRequest,
    HttpEvent,
    HttpResponse,
    HttpErrorResponse
} from "@angular/common/http";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { tap } from "rxjs/operators";
import "rxjs/add/operator/do";

@Injectable()
export class HttpInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(private router: Router) {}


    intercept(
        req: HttpRequest<any>,
        next: HttpHandler
    ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        if (
            localStorage.getItem("jwtToken") !== "" &&
            localStorage.getItem("jwtToken") !== null
        ) {
            const JWT = localStorage.getItem("jwtToken");
            req = req.clone({
                setHeaders: {
                    Authorization: JWT
                }
            });
        }

        return next.handle(req).pipe(
            tap((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
                console.log(event);
                // handle error here
            }),
            tap((err: any) => {

                console.log(err);
            })
        );

    }
}
```

Comment: I get an error on `import { do } from 'rxjs/operators'` that there is no exported member... do you also have `rxjs-compat` in your project? I updated to rxjs to 6.2.1 which is the newest version in my opinion.

Comment: yes i am use rxjs-compat. please check updated answer.